# Can .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library depend on .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

In one of my .NET Framework projects, I introduced a new .NET Standard 2.0 project. This project has dependencies on some existing .NET Framework projects. I was wondering if this is right to do.?
The reason I added a .NETStandard project is that we have plans to move the whole repository to .NET Core / Standard. Hence I thought, the new project we add can target .NET Standard.  With .NET Standard project I get the new SDK style project file, package references, etc by default.

The consuming application is still .NET Framework.

Do I have to retarget the new project to .NET Framework 4.7.2 so that the project will have the above SDK style project file and package references but targets .NET Framework 4.7.2 now. It will then be as easy as changing the target framework when we move to .NET Core?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Can you eleborate.? I'll update the question with my purpose

Comment: @MichaelRandall Please

Comment: it would be extremely usual, the norm would be to convert those which can to std 2 and then reference in others not the other way around. so 4.7.2 refs std 2 and then when you start the core... it can also ref the std 2

Comment: Please read your comment and explain to me what you understand..
@Seabizkit

Comment: that you want to ref 4.7.2 on a std 2.0

Comment: I know I want to.. The question is `is that meant to be done that way.`

Comment: please re-read my previous comment the one you asked me to re-read.

Comment: @Seabizkit it's hard to understand, friend :(

Comment: make libs... make then std 2.0, those can be referenced in others libs like 4.7 and core 3 but you can not reference 4.7 or core 3 from a std 2.0. basically to convert its not simple and unless you have basically a very well formed lib structure before then its probably not viable. you would be better off explaining you current solution structure and references. basically convert those that can, .... unfortunately will probably none or 1, convert to std 2. I cant say as i dont know your solution.

Comment: perhaps this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard
`The following table lists the minimum platform` also https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard

Comment: less "portable"* (4.7) code should reference more portable (std 2).. not the other way around otherwise anything that wanted to reference that would also need to be its own lowest level. aka if you have a std 2 that references a 4.7 then the min of that project is locked to 4.7 as the next lib which references also needs to have 4.7, not even sure if that possible, hence i asked what happened when you tired, as it wouldn't make sense. What this requires you to do is break down you projects into more usable less depend parts.

Comment: This is usually quite hard as the 4.7 were never designed with this in mind. 
if you adding new then yes std 2.0 is the way to go if you are wanting to be able to share this lib with a 4.7. Your new added libs of std 2.0, should not reference other libs which are not also std 2.0 or you are breaking the re-usable model and then creating dependencies which would be another dependencies which would stop `plans to move the whole repository to .NET Core / Standard.`

Comment: @nilsK does the comment above help

Comment: @Seabizkit yes it does. bit since Jins is more rude then thankful for the free help he gets, i'm not really motivated to paritcipate in this discussion anymore. kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0

> .NET Framework compatibility mode
> Starting with .NET Standard 2.0, the .NET Framework compatibility mode was introduced. This compatibility mode allows .NET Standard projects to reference .NET Framework libraries as if they were compiled for .NET Standard. Referencing .NET Framework libraries doesn't work for all projects, such as libraries that use Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) APIs.

This is necessary as an intermediate step for some projects, but in order to get to your final goal you will of course have to go all in on .net core which will require updating those projects not to use framework or they will crash at runtime.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was askinh. I am sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your purpose of introducing the Standard 2.0 project. Normally, you make a Standard when you need it to be accessible both from .NET Framework and Core. In your case, your Standard project won't be operable from Core under macOS or Linux.

Comment: Updated by question. Right now, we don't need the project to support macOS or Linux. That will be required when we move all our whole solution to .NETCore/ .NETStandard

Comment: In this case, I can't see any reason to use Standard at all. EF Core 5.0 won't support Standard.

Comment: I never said anything about EFCore.. Are you familiar with PackageReferences and the SDK Style project files  compared to .NETFramework project  csproj file visual studio generates?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy: the reason to use netstandard would be so that you can take an incremental approach, and make your dependencies netstandard one at a time.  If you have a solution with even 10 libraries that your main app depends upon, it would be a bit of a pain to make all 11 projects core at the same time.  If you make the libraries net standard 1 at a time, you can (a) work on libraries independently of each other (i.e. multiple teams can work on it without interfering with each other), and (b) leave the project that can't be both until there's no conflict.